# IsDebuggingEnabled from inside ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've got an ASP.NET Web API controller and a `public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoThing()` method inside of it.

Without accessing `HttpContext.Current` (the method has to be unit-testable), how can I determine if `IsDebuggingEnabled` for the current request?

None of these objects have this property:

- `this.Request`
- `this.RequestContext`
- `this.ActionContext`
- `this.ControllerContext`

Where do I look, to find `IsDebuggingEnabled`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled
```

This property actually looks at the web.config configuration setting and its only in the HttpContext.
the following should work:

```
var cfg =(System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/compilation");
if (cfg.Debug)
{
...
}
```